# How to draw X using arrays?

Tags: java

Does anyone have an idea how to print X from given number?
e.g.:

given number 5.
So, I should print

```
 X000X
 0X0X0
 00X00
 0X0X0
 X000X
```

This is my code, still missing something on it

```
public static void drawX(int number){
    int[][] draw = new int[number][number];
    for(int i = 0; i< number; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k<=i; k++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j = number-1; j>i; j--){
            if(j == number-1 || j == i+1)
                System.out.print("X ");
            else
                System.out.print("  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< number; i++){
        for(int v = number; v>i; v--){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j = 0; j<i; j++){
            System.out.print("X ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
 }
```

Comment: What did you try? Are you familiar with two dimensional arrays and loops?

Comment: Also, post your code.

Comment: I have tried iterate using for loops, but the result is still wrong

Comment: So add that code. Then we can tell you whats wrong iin it

Comment: @user8352237 That's a great start. Show us this code, you might have a minor issue, or completely misunderstood something. You will learn from your mistake much more if we help you correct **your** answer, rather than provide a new one.

Comment: simple loop where index (i) and (length-i-1) are x

Comment: @amit **You** should help OP.

Comment: @saka1029 (1) I did. (2) I am not following this instruction. This is not my job, I **can** help the OP, nobody is enforcing me to do it.

Comment: I found it! thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

See **comments on your code** below, highlighting some issues I've noticed. It probably won't solve everything straight away, but it will give you a push in the right direction I hope.

```
public static void drawX(int number){
    // draw is never used.
    int[][] draw = new int[number][number];
    for(int i = 0; i< number; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k<=i; k++){
            // Here we print a " " even for k == i.
            // Are you sure you want k <= i ?
            // If you change it, dont forget to also change
            // stop clause in next loop.
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j = number-1; j>i; j--){
            if(j == number-1 || j == i+1)
                // j == number -1 prints X only in the last column
                // Maybe you wanted number - i - 1?
                // j == i+1 means you "skip" the ith element.
                // Why the extra space after X?
                System.out.print("X ");
            else
                // Why two spaces here?
                System.out.print("  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< number; i++){
        for(int v = number; v>i; v--){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j = 0; j<i; j++){
            // here you need to do very similar logic to 
            // what you did in previous loop, when printing first
            // 'number' lines.
            System.out.print("X ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
 }
```